# How to fix inconsistent spacing above tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

I notice that the amount of spacing above `tabular` changes depending on whether I have one row or more than one row:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Foo

\begin{tabular}{l}
    Foo
\end{tabular}

Foo

\begin{tabular}{l}
    Foo \\
    Foo
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces the output:

[image]

The space above the first tabular environment, which only has one line, is greater than the space above the second tabular environment, which has two lines. I like the amount of space that is above the one-line tabular environment, but how can I ensure the same amount of space will be above the two-line tabular environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stems from the default *centred* vertical alignment of `tabular`. Either

1. Issue `\strut` as part of the middle non-`tabular` Foo. This will ensure a proper baseline to butt up against (vertically):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   Foo

   \begin{tabular}{l}
     Foo
   \end{tabular}

   \strut
   Foo

   \begin{tabular}{l}
     Foo \\ Foo
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Let the second `tabular` be `[t]`op-aligned:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   Foo

   \begin{tabular}{l}
     Foo
   \end{tabular}

   Foo

   \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
     Foo \\ Foo
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

In both instances, the desired outcome is achieved:

[image]